Use of "us" as personal determinative
Consider this sentence:

There is lots of stuff in us shoppers' carts.

I know it is awkward but I am interested in whether it is grammatically correct. Should "us" be changed to "we"?
A very similar question may be found at “A threat to us people” or “a threat to we people”?.

If I'm reading the question right, are you asking whether the personal determinative can be used with a possessive? That's tricky, because we already have possessive determiners like our, so "our shoppers' carts" is what I'd prefer. But I could imagine someone on the fly making "us shoppers" into "us shoppers' carts," so I'd have to research it more.

Grammatically, the sentence means that we are _shoppers' carts".

Casual folks saying casual things like "There is lots of stuff in ..." don't necessarily need to correct that mess if they are getting across what they mean. We get that think their carts are full -- okay.

"In the carts of us shoppers" would be better. But certainly, I don't know why you'd want to change from objective "us" to subjective "we" in this case, any more than in the linked question. English uses "us" after prepositions.

I'd say that it sounds so slangy that it is arguably unacceptable on outlandish grounds (violating Orwell's sixth law: don't say anything that sounds grotesque / unnatural) whether or not someone can argue persuasively for or against grammaticality. I'd use  'There is lots of stuff in our – the shoppers' – carts.' [John Lawler; possessives with appositives]

What @EdwinAshworth said. Personally, I'd normally parse There's lots of stuff in them shoppers' carts as equivalent to ...those shoppers' carts rather than ...in the carts of they / them who are shoppers. So idiomatically it's not really comparable to us shoppers' carts, which can only really be parsed as ...in the carts of we / us who are shoppers. But syntactically, I see no difference.

I am just wondering whether the sentence is grammatically correct as stated or would be correct if "us" were replaced by "we." I saw something equivalent (using "us") in a book recently. I can supply the reference if anyone wants it.

We shoppers’ carts have lots of stuff = Our carts have lots of stuff = There’s lots of stuff in our carts = There’s lots of stuff in we shoppers’ carts

I'm almost convinced by this that it should be 'we".

If the book is reasonably received, especially an accepted grammar, please give an attributed and linked quote. If not, it's hardly worth mentioning. There's a lot of ungrammatical writing on offer. // Note that your example here is not parallel to say 'There are increased costs to us shoppers' where either of the nominals is deletable without the whole becoming ungrammatical. Both occupy object slots, and 'us' is here correspondingly in the objective case.

The construction is rare, but not so rare that examples of both cannot be found. As the data set is tiny though, there's unlikely to be a consensus about which one is 'correct', except from a prescriptivist point of view that says since the item in question is a determiner in an NP determiner of an NP acting as object of the preposition, it likely should have the accusative case. This follows the logic at the similar question in the OP where the determiner was simply that of the NP acting as object of the preposition. But then there are counter examples, and I had an easier time finiding examples for we than us, possibly because of the overlap with US meaning United States. From a descriptivist standpoint, it seems either is possible.
we

If anyone in Scotland has any doubt about our real value to the
English and how we’re completely subsumed in the UK, how they dominate
the UK and regard everyone as English, let this woman’s complete
dismissal of we Scots’ existence and right to have our own
national identity resonate in their ears when entering the booth to
vote independence or not. (The National)
Tried today to get a copy of the Draft Annual Plan from the Service
Centre but there were only two copies and was told I could not take
one away but could copy any pages I would like….A very expensive Draft
Plan and I had ten pages copied in black and white (not the brilliant
colours this document was) once again a waste of we ratepayers’
money (Comments at Wellington Scoop)
I was heartened to hear that Sony will coming out with a firmware
update to address many of we users’ complaints about the user
interface, but it’s unclear exactly what is changing other than some
video changes. (Sony Alpha Rumors)
Having said that I don’t agree with Dan’s critique of we orthotrots’
view of the theory, but let it be… (Comments at NewPol)

us

“It makes me feel as if it’s me and my sister and the rest of us
students’ rights are now compromised and not a priority to this
school whatsoever,” he said. (Student quote at NY Post)
"It’s an utter disaster. It has really taken away three years of us
pensioners' lives and at a time when we need peace and quiet. It’s
put an enormous strain on people like myself but it has ruined the
area completely," he said. (Pensioner quote at WalesOnline)


If anyone can supply a definitive answer, I would be interested. Until then, I will suppose that either "us" or "we" is acceptable.

@Richard Hevener
But "there's unlikely to be a consensus about which one is 'correct' ..." must mean that some will find it unacceptable. The sensible course is to rephrase.

@Edwin Ashworth I'm interested in this only as a technical grammar question, but perhaps there is no correct answer.

The famed grammarians Quirk and Svartvik, in 'Investigating Linguistic Acceptability' (1966), proposed a five-point scale for the degree of acceptability of individual grammatical constructions when they found that graduate students of English Language disagreed on the acceptability of certain test sentences. Usage panels are often thus divided. In English, there's no grammar czar, no Académie, to make dictatorial pronouncements on grammaticality in grey areas (and the French people tend to vote with their feet, ignoring such diktats, 'definitive answers', anyway).
